# Html a href stopped working

Tags: html, download, href

I have a file on a server and up to some time users were able to just click on it to download the file, but not any more. The right mouse click and "Save Link As.." still works just fine, so there is nothing wrong with the file or the path.@ this point I´m going mental since the code was not changed and it is dead simple. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<p> 
    <a href="../files/test1file.doc" download><img src="../Data/img/icon-word.gif" width="140" height="130" alt="bla bla" /></a>
    <a href="../files/test2file.doc" download><img src="../Data/img/icon-word.gif" width="135" height="130" alt="bla bla 2" /></a>
</p>
```

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: did you show complete url in href?

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and Firefox. The path in the code I posted is just as it is in my code.

Comment: What is the specific error? Any HTTP-Error? Any Browser-Error? What is the browser log saying?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not check previously for error @ browser error console. I have couple Bootstrap's & JavaScript issues. After fixing them up I will report to you all.